# Missing desktop icons after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, 22.04, .desktop

While on 20.04, I had some `*.desktop` files in `~/Desktop`. Those worked and properly displayed an icon on my desktop.

After the upgrade to 22.04, the icons are gone. Google told me the files should be in `~/.local/share/applications`, so I moved them there, but that hasn't helped.

`desktop-file-validate` (from `desktop-file-utils` package) says the files are valid.

How do I get my desktop icons back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your upgrade probably went slightly wrong. The Gnome Shell extension that provides icons on the desktop may not have been activated, or may not have been correctly installed.

- Install `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`. Open that tool by searching "Extensions" in the Application Overview. In the section "Build-in", check whether the "Desktop Icons NG" extension is listed. If yes, it is probably turned off. Turning it on should make the icons appear.
- If the extension is not there, quit "Extensions", install the extension with the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng`, log out then back in. The extension automatically will be enabled. Else, turn it on in "Extensions".

Comment: Exactly right! BTW, I also had to move the files back to `~/Desktop`, so that location was correct in the first place.

Comment: Worked for me after a restart. More specifically:
1. Installed gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
2. Reopened Extensions, but the new extension wasn't there.
3. Restarted.
4. Desktop icons reappeared (the extension was enabled automatically).

Comment: @igorrs Thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer to be precise about this.